# add custom rule to sonar gate

Tags: java, static, sonarqube

we have multi module java web project and for check quality of code we are using sonar.

we have a problem that we write the Validator.java utility class and check the validity of input inside of it. for example for String text, instead of validation of null in service class we call Validator.isNull() but sonar not detect our utility and i don't want to exclude this rule because  if really some not validated input we don't understate.

my question is how to write a custom rule to detect our validator utility for null checking.

Thanks;